# C# HtmlAgilityPack HtmlDocument() LoadHtml encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://localhost/rgm.php");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString(url);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc23 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc23.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNode body23 = doc23.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

string content23 = body23.InnerHtml;
```

How can i force this to parse web page with "UTF-8" encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DownloadData` method of WebClient instead of `DownloadString()`:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadData(url);
var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use MemoryStream

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData("http://localhost/rgm.php"));

HtmlDocument doc23 = new HtmlDocument();
doc23.Load(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

HtmlNode body23 = doc23.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
string content23 = body23.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be an alternative .

```
string url = "http://localhost/rgm.php";
            var Webget = new HtmlWeb();

 Webget.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            var doc23 = Webget.Load(url);

HtmlNode body23 = doc23.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
string content23 = body23.InnerHtml;
```